# What is this pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, language-agnostic

I have a few classes that perform background tasks that might raise exceptions. They all implement the following interface:

```
public interface HowDoYouCallMe {
    void addExceptionHandler(ExceptionHandler handler);
}
```

When one of the background tasks raises an exception, all the ExceptionHandlers are informed of the exception so that it can be properly handled / propagated.

How would you call the interface? ExceptionHandlerObservable (not great)?

Comment: What's wrong with `ExceptionHandlerObservable`?

Comment: Why are people voting to close as Off-topic? Please don't, it's a reasonable question

Comment: I'm sure if it gets closed there will be enough people to vote to reopen it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It looks like the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) applied to exception handling. So the interface would probably be named `ExceptionObservable` or something of the sort.

Comment: Then the ExceptionHandler could be renamed to ExceptionObserver, so that it implies it is the second part of the Observable pattern.

Answer (score 3):

If you think of an exception being thrown as an event then maybe this is close to the [EventBroker design pattern](http://msforge.net/blogs/paki/archive/2007/11/20/EventBroker-implementation-in-C_2300_-full-source-code.aspx).  Maybe you can call this one ExceptionBroker.

Comment: I like the idea but it seems to be linked to singleton patterns in network messaging, so maybe misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Call it `IObservableException`.

Comment: The last part was unnecessary.

Comment: lol, it was a really good point!!! can't believe the masses will now not get enlightened!

Comment: I'm tempted to -1 this. Neither one of those conforms to the Java naming conventions (they look more like C#?), and the second one is clearly bad advice. Fortunately, I don't think there's any risk the OP will take it.

Comment: feel free to...it was just my opinion. I am in the C# world after all. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd just call it something like "HandlesExceptions"

Comment: Naming things is subjective, but I'm pretty sure that calling an interface `HandlesExceptions` is not very good.

Comment: To add to @Lirik's point, the interface is generally written after the verb `implements`, so the name should be an adjective/noun, not a verb

Comment: Actually, it doesn't *handle* exceptions, it *raises* exceptions which can be handled by another, external class.

Comment: Or maybe it *processes* them.

Answer (score -1):

Just like IDisposable and ICloneable, this class can be named as IExceptionHandlerObservable